# Modal Bootstrap appear when the form is correct

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a problem with Bootstrap modal and jquery.validate, i am using a modal bootstrap for the error messages, the windows modal appear when the form is correct, this is my Js code, the modal appear with the showerrorsfunction

```
 $("#form").validate({
        errorElement: "em",
        errorContainer: "#myModal",
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
              error.prependTo('#myModal');
            },
    rules: {
         "tRemision": {
             minlength: 5,
             number: true
             }
     },
      submitHandler: function(form) { 
          form.submit();
          document.getElementById("b1").value = "Running...";
          document.getElementById("b2").disabled = true;
          return true; 
          },
    errorLabelContainer: $("#myModal p"),
    success: function() {
        $('#myModal').modal("hide");
      },
    onblur: false,
    onkeyup: false,
    onsubmit: true,
    onfocusout: false,
    onkeyup: false,
    onclick: false,
    /*debug: true,*/
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        $('#myModal').modal();
         this.defaultShowErrors();
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my own question with this code, the option errorPlacement was the solution:

```
$("#button").on("click", function() {
    $("#form").validate({
        onblur: false,
        onkeyup: false,
        onsubmit: true,
        onfocusout: false,
        onkeyup: false,
        onclick: false,   
        errorPlacement: function(error, element){
            $("#MyModal, p").empty();
            error.appendTo("#MyModal, p");      
            $("#myModal").modal('show');

        },
        rules: {
            "textbox": {number: true,   minlength: 5}
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) { 
            document.getElementById("button").value = "Running...";
            document.getElementById("button").disabled = true;
            return true; 
         }
    });
    });
```